# Iterating through array with condition to create new array

Tags: arrays, scala, for-loop

How can I iterate through an array and assign its `val`?
I tried the following two approaches but they did not work:

```
var a : Array[String] = Array("foo","bar")
var b : Array[String] = Array()
for (i <- 0 to (a.length-1)) {
    println(a(i))
    b :+ a(i)
}
```

and

```
var a : Array[String] = Array("foo","bar")
var b : Array[String] = Array()
for (element <- a){
    println(element)
    b :+ element
}
```

So the println works but they assignment doesn't.

I am really frustated since it seems so easy and I do note get it. :(

Comment: Try b = b ++ element

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the Standard Library do the copying for you.

```
val a : Array[String] = Array("foo","bar")
val b : Array[String] = a.clone()
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because `:+` isn't an assignment operator. This statement, for example, `Array() :+ "str"` doesn't modify the `Array`, it creates a new `Array` with the modified value. Unfortunately your code doesn't assign that new `Array` to a new or existing variable so the modification is lost.

You could do something like this ...

```
for (element <- a){
  b = b :+ element
}
```

... but there are better ways to get this done.

**update**

To filter string elements for multiple unrelated qualities you might try this.

```
val acceptableRE = "(f.*|ba.*)".r
val a: Array[String] = Array("foo", "bar", "buf", "bba")
val b: Array[String] = a.collect{case acceptableRE(s) => s}   // Array(foo, bar)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That makes sense. Actually I do not want to clone it but apply some cases afterwards to eliminate some values of the array. Thus I am using this for loop. Or what can you suggest to do that in a better way?

Comment: So `b` is supposed to be a copy of `a` but with some values removed? If that's the case then go with Jyothi Babu Araja's suggestion and use `filter` (or `filterNot`, depending on the condition to be tested).

Comment: This would mean that I have a seperate filter for each step? Like `val b = a.filter(el => el.startsWith("f")).filter(el => el.startsWith("ba"))`??

Comment: Obviously not. No element will start with both "f" and "ba". See my update.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [.filter](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#filter(p:A=%3EBoolean):Repr) of `Array` to filter with condition.

Try this example with element length as condition

```
val a : Array[String] = Array("foo","bars")
val b = a.filter(el => el.length > 3)
```

**Note:** Better use `val` to avoid mutability.